# Nexus 5 Change Resolution/DPI

Tags: nexus-5, screen-resolution

Is it possible to change the resolution or DPI of the Nexus 5? I've read somewhere that you can do this with a Nexus tablet. I will be needing an Android device for development and I am considering the Nexus 5.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't change the *actual* screen size or DPI, because those are physical characteristics of the screen hardware.  You can't stretch the phone to be the size of a tablet, or change how the LCD is wired.

On a rooted device, you can edit a configuration file to change how big Android *thinks* the screen is, which will affect the calculated DPI and the resulting layouts.  That isn't convenient for testing, though, because rendering a "larger" screen's UI on a smaller screen will result in tiny text that's hard to read and tiny touch elements that are hard to interact with.

For testing a variety of screen sizes, you're better off creating a variety of AVDs in the emulator.  That's much simpler and less dangerous than rooting and editing low-level system configuration files just to test a layout.

Comment: But can I test 'Smaller' screen sizes on the Nexus 5 for example?

Comment: You could, yes.  But it's still simpler and safer to use an AVD.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely change the screen density (DPI) in your build.prop file using a tool like [Build Prop Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.apps.build.prop.editor). Note that you will need a **rooted** device in order to tweak your build.prop. You will want to change the '*ro.sf.lcd_density*' key to a smaller value to make everything smaller (higher density); likewise, you will want to change it to a larger value to make everything bigger (lower density). *I recommend you stay within the range of **100 - 600** dpi, as that covers almost all devices out there.*